# Jython modules through the Java ScriptEngine API

Tags: java, eclipse, jython

**Background:**

I've created an application that takes one Jython script and evaluates it in Java using the ScriptEngine API. The Jython script file I evaluate imports other custom made Jython modules and uses their classes. I've been working in Eclipse and in order for the Jython script to import other modules I had to create an External Class Folder where all the Jython scripts sat, including the one I evaluate. I then had to add that folder to the classpath. With this set up in Eclipse everything works.

I now have to prepare my application for release and went to test it outside of Eclipse. I put the Jython scripts in a folder and added that folder to the classpath similar to this line,

```
    java -cp ./;C:\MyApplication\Jython.jar;C:\MyApplication\JythonModulesFolder Main argument1_script
```

The program works as expected (outside of Eclipse) with a simple test case of a Jython script containing,

```
    print "Jython Working"
```

But when I try to use the Jython script that uses other custom Jython modules the evaluation fails. Again all Jython scripts have been properly tested in Eclipse and succeed.

**Question:**

I think the problem is the Jython Scripts/Modules are not properly being set to the classpath like they were in Eclipse.

So how can I mimic my environment like in Eclipse to get my Jython Modules visible?

**Eclipse:**

Kepler

**Relevant Installed Software on Eclipse:**

Jython Development Tools (JyDt) version 1.4.15 provider Red Robin Software

**Update:**

I'm able to do this in my Jython script,

```
    from my.java.packageJar import *
    import sys
```

But I am not able to import the Jython logging,

```
    import logging
```

Along with all my custom modules. But if I include the logging modules from the Jython lib folder I am able to `import logging`. Does this mean there are modules I need from the Jython bin that allow me to import external files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had to add

```
    jython2.5.3\Lib
```

to my classpath. For reference here is part of my script,

```
    java.exe -cp "%APP_HOME%\lib\jython.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\Hammer.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\gmsecapi.jar;%APP_HOME%\examples\Python;C:\jython2.5.3\Lib;%CLASSPATH%" bridenstine.hammer.main.Main %*
```